# WPF focus row of datagrid with only XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I can set the focus with only XAML to a Datagrid.
It eludes me how (if possible at all) how to set focus to the first row *with only XAML*.

My (shortened) XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WhatIsInTheBarnBooth.MainWindow"
    ...
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=grdData}">
</Window>

<DataGrid Name="grdData">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try....

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid}"
```

and

```
<DataGrid Name="grdData" SelectedIndex="0">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. [whoever down voted - please come back and remove your downvote. all is forgiven]